# QRubberband is not fixed on QGraphicsScene. If i minimise the window means the QRubberband is showing on desktop

Tags: c++, qt

I am inserting `Qrubberband` Object on the viewport. like below

```
auto viewport = QGraphicScene->views().first()->viewport();
 if (!rubberBandInstalled)
 {
    viewport->installEventFilter(&rubberBand);
 }
```

The Below function for drawing `QRubberband`.

```
void RubberBand::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) { 
    if (event->buttons() != Qt::LeftButton) return; 
    if (rubberBand.isVisible()) {
        rubberBand.hide(); 
        return; 
     } 
     auto posItem = RelativeClippedCoordinates(event->globalPos()); 
     origin = CoordinatesItemToGlobal(pixmapItem, posItem); 
     selectionRect.setTopLeft(posItem); 
     rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize())); 
     rubberBand.setStyleSheet("background-color:trasparent;"); 
     rubberBand.show(); 
}
```

after minimising window. the rubberband is appearing on desktop

[image]

Comment: Here is the complete code.  https://github.com/stil/qimvi

Comment: There's no question here?

Comment: It should not go outside window. But it is going.

Comment: After drawing rubberband on image. if i minimise the window of GUI. The rubberband is appearing like above image. I want rubberband always on QGraphicview

Comment: You're creating the `QRubberBand` *without* a parent.  That will make it a top level window -- hence the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: How can i create a with parent? Because the QRubberband object is initialized in other class. and i am handling all my QRubberband tasks in other class. Please help me. I am new to qt.

Comment: Please, have a look at Qt doc. of constructor: [`QRubberBand::QRubberBand(Shape s, QWidget * p = Q_NULLPTR)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html#QRubberBand): _Constructs a rubber band of shape s, with parent p._ If you do not pass the 2nd arg. then it is `Q_NULLPTR` (which means "no parent") by default and it is as described by @G.M.